# Is it correct and natural to respond with "interested in" in this context?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I was told:

> Glad to come across someone who knows Theology.

My (proposed) response:

> It's my pleasure to find someone else interested in Theology on the other side of the World.

I am unsure whether to use *interested in* or *interested by*. Google Translate gives me the impression that I may be wrong.

Comment: Have you looked in a dictionary? (Google Translate is not a dictionary.)

Comment: *Interested in* is fine, but why is *theology* capitalized? And why is *world*? English does not capitalize random words in the middle of a sentence.

Answer (score 2):

The main difference between *interested in* and *interested by* is that *interested in* usually refers to a serious interest, e.g. the study of something, whereas *interested by* refers to a casual interest, e.g. something that you just think is interesting.

In this context, you would want to use *interested in*. Note that *interested in* is the more often used form. If in doubt, use *interested in*.

Answer (score 0):

The normal preposition after "interested" is "in" as in "She is very interested in music". Latin "inter-" is a variant of "in" so the preposition "in" after "interested" simply repeats
the Latin prefix "inter-".

Maybe you occasionally find the variant "by" after "interested". I would not say that there is a semantic difference (a difference in meaning), it is just a variant that logically fits. But the normal use is "interested + in", at least in British English.

Comment: _Inter_ is not a variant of _in_ in Latin; it is an extension of it with a different meaning. Just like ‘throughout’ isn’t a variant of ‘through’ in English.

Comment: Absolutely right. I did not want to talk about Latin words (in and inter), I just wanted to say in inter- is the word element in.